# Code push from GitHub to Google App Engine

Tags: git, google-app-engine, github

I have an application on the Github repository, and would send it to the GAE (google app engine). How can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: One's a code repo, the other is an app platform. App Engine has directions on how to deploy to it, I suggest you follow those.

Comment: Is it an application written for App Engine? If not, you can't.

Comment: You mean the solution will always side GAE? Github not need to do anything, right?

Comment: I have an application ready on Github, I just want to run it on GAE, simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App Engine supports "Push to Deploy" which can do almost exactly this!

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy

You'll probably have to actually clone your repo, then push from it locally, but that should be easy.

Update 19/09/2016: The previous link is broken, the current way to connect to some external repo is treated in the section [Connecting a Hosted Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories)

Comment: And it has to be an application written for appengine specifically, not any old bit of code in git will work ;-)

Comment: fyi this was working for me, with some missed pushes, however now it just fails to build completely. Seems rather buggy.

Comment: Hi! I connected my github repo to gae but when I push from local to remote github's repo, gae doesn't upgrade my website. How can I get and auto-deploy? Thanks for reply :)

Comment: This feature was discontinued a while ago. The way to go now is hosting your own CD, i.e. Jenkins on a Compute Engine instance.