# Google App Engine automatic pull from github

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I have a github repository connected to my app engine project. [I followed this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868309/from-github-to-google-app-engine).

I need an option to do an automatic pull from remote repository on app engine when I push to master.

I already have a php file. Maybe I must delete this file before connection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically deploying from a git-repository was discontinued a while ago! The way to go now is hosting your own continuous delivery-system, i.e. Jenkins on a Compute Engine instance. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385874/198996

Comment: Thank you very much :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the official GCP App Engine action:

https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine

Here's an example GitHub workflow:

```
# Using https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine
# The following example service account permissions could be required for a Typescript project.
# *****
# App Engine Admin
# Cloud Build Editor
# Compute Admin
# Service Account User
# Storage Admin
# *****

name: App Engine Deploy

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the development branch
  push:
    branches: [master]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  # workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  app-deploy:
    # needs: build # Job defined in another file.
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - id: "auth"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
        with:
          credentials_json: "${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}"

      - id: "deploy"
        uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v0.5.0"

      - id: "test"
        run: 'curl "${{ steps.deploy.outputs.url }}"'
```

Run the following Gist code snippet to get a proper `yml` file:

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/baharalidurrani/1af42b29f809f0cafeabf47672f8e590.js"></script>
```